# Include CMS Block in Template includes HTML-Tag and Doctype

Tags: static-block, magento-1.7.0.1

We have some problems when we include static cms blocks into the template with our Magento 1.7.0.1

We include the cms block this way:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms-block-name')->toHtml() ?>
```

The problem is that the Doctype and HTML-Structure is included everytime with the cms block. We don't know how and can't find a way to fix it.

Comment: This should't happen. Check if your block does not actually contain the doctype.  Disable the editor and take a look at the actual content.

Comment: Hello Marius. We have searched a wile but we found the problem. We disabled extension after extension. Problem is the Ikantam_Internalseolinking extension. Now it still works an is valid. Patrick

Comment: Post what you found as an answer and mark it as accepted.